# Pandas: indexing a multidimensional key

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm working with a CSV file which is shown here below:

```
strain  contig          homology
1A42    ctg.s1.000000F  Chr
1A42    ctg.s1.000001F  pSymA
1A42    ctg.s1.3        pSymB
1A42    ctg.s2.000000F  Other
4B41    ctg.s1.000000F  Chr
4B41    ctg.s1.3        pSymA
4B41    ctg.s1.1        pSymB
7B22    ctg.s2.12       other
7B22    ctg.s1.000000F  Chr
7B22    ctg.s1.3        pSymA
7B22    ctg.s1.1        pSymB
8A52    ctg.s1.0        pSymB
8A52    ctg.s1.4        Chr
8A52    ctg.s1.2        pSymA
```

In the `contig` column some strings are repeated among the different strains of the `strain` column. For example, `ctg.s1.000000F` is present in `1A42`, `4B41` and `7B22`.

I wrote the following lines of code to define a function in which, given the strain name and the CSV file as input, it prints back the corresponding value in the `homology` column for each `contig` value:

```
def myfunction(strain, csv):
    with open(csv, 'r') as h:
        h_df = pd.read_csv(h, index_col=False, dtype='unicode', on_bad_lines='skip', sep=";")
        match = h_df.loc[(h_df == strain).any(1), 'contig']
        for element in match:
            contig = h_df.loc[(h_df == element).any(1), 'homology']
            print(element, contig)


myfunction(1A42, mycsv)
```

It actually works but returns me the homology values of the entire column and only the "1A42" related ones.

How can I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (simpler) approach:

```
def myfunction(strain, csv):
    with open(csv, 'r') as h:
        h_df = pd.read_csv(h, index_col=False, dtype='unicode', on_bad_lines='skip', sep=";")
    print(h_df[h_df['strain'] == strain][['homology', 'contig']])
```